# How to merge 2 Dataframe with different length and keep all the position of first dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

As the question declares on the title, I would like to merge and maintain the position of the left data frame using Python. Specifically, the 2 data frames are as below:

```
df1.head()
>>
                Time    
2007-01-01      20:01:00    
2007-01-01      20:38:00    
2007-01-01      22:39:00    
2007-01-02      00:45:00    
2007-01-02      02:33:00
...
```

```
df2.head()
>>
           Time_Signal
Time                                
00:00:00        1
00:01:00        1
00:02:00        1
00:03:00        1
00:04:00        0
...
```

The minute is the min unit of 'Time'. So, how to merge df2 to df1 and keep all the position of the row in df1
I have tried to make 'Time' column become an index of both data frames, then merge using the code:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But it's output is not as desired

```
merged.head()
>>
            Time        Time_Signal
index                                           
2007-01-25  00:00:00        1
2007-03-16  00:00:00        1
2007-09-21  00:00:00        1
2007-10-22  00:00:00        1
2008-03-12  00:00:00        1
...
```

My desired result is as below with the row of df1 is maintained

```
df1.head()
>>
                  Time      Time_Signal
2007-01-01      20:01:00         0
2007-01-01      20:38:00         0
2007-01-01      22:39:00         1
2007-01-02      00:45:00         1
2007-01-02      02:33:00         0
...
```

Thank for help!

Comment: Is the index of right dataframe similar to that of the left @ShanN

Comment: @Vishnudev yes, I've made it same

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question completely. df2 index is not date (like in df1) so "on" what are you joining the tables?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague so i'll make some assumptions and you can correct me in the comments.

Let's build a small example and see if it solve your problem.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3], 'time': [3, 4, 5]})
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df1
Out[143]: 
    time
id      
1      3
2      4
3      5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'time': [3, 4], 'time_signal': [7, 8]})
df2 = df2.set_index('id')
df2
Out[144]: 
    time  time_signal
id                   
1      3            7
2      4            8

df1.join(df2, lsuffix='df1')
    timedf1  time  time_signal
id                            
1         3   3.0          7.0
2         4   4.0          8.0
3         5   NaN          NaN
```

So you need to set both indexes as the dates in your example so a join operation could be made. Then, you just join (which automatically joins on the index)

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `merge` by column `Time` in `df1` with `df2.index`:

```
print (df1['Time'])
2007-01-01    20:01:00
2007-01-01    20:38:00
2007-01-01    22:39:00
2007-01-02    00:45:00
2007-01-02    02:33:00
Name: Time, dtype: object

print (df2.index)
Index(['20:01:00', '00:01:00', '00:02:00', '00:03:00', '00:04:00'],
      dtype='object', name='Time')
```

Also types has to be same - strings, times or timedeltas in both:

```
print (type(df1['Time'].iat[0]))
<class 'str'>

print (type(df2.index[0]))
<class 'str'>
```

---

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='Time', right_index=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

create those two dataframes to dictionary then merger it and convert merged dictionary to dataframe.It will work

Comment: there must be a better way!